# Is it possible to use system environment variables in Qt resource file?

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to import some of resources from another project without copying into my project directory. Environment variable `ANOTHER_PROJECT_DIR` stores path to another project.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
<file>%ANOTHER_PROJECT_DIR%/file</file>
```

or this:

```
<file>$$(ANOTHER_PROJECT_DIR)/file</file>
```

in my qrc file.

So is it possible to use system environment variables in Qt resource file and how can I do it?

It would be great to find crossplatform solution

Answer (score 1):

**qrc** resource file is a static binary resource link. You cannot do it dynamically. However, you can do something like this from your code

```
#include <QProcessEnvironment>
...
somefunc(){
   QString env = qgetenv("SOME_VAR");   
   QString filepath = env + "/path/to/file";

...
}
```

Comment: I need to do it at compile time, not runtime. I want the resources from another project to build in my binary. So static binary resource link is pretty good for this case. It just need to be properly processed

Answer (score 0):

Rcc does not support such functionality. You can use qmake's "substitutes" (still undocumented?) feature instead.

> test.pro

```
myqrc.input = myqrc.in
myqrc.output = myqrc.qrc
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += myqrc
```

> myqrc.in

```
<file>$$(ANOTHER_PROJECT_DIR)/file</file>
```

Basically, "substitutes" is a builtin preprocessor capable of evaluating/expanding "qmake"-expressions (plus `!!IF` / `!!ELSE` / `!!ENDIF` conditional).